# Querying all users who were invited to a large event (>50K users) returns capped results (<5K users)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am trying to query all of the Facebook UIDs of users that were invited to one Facebook event. (I'm using this data to analyse trends, with the users's UID being a key part of the formula.) More than 50000 users were invited to the event, which I would like to query. When making a Graph API query (`256633941116408/invited`) or FQL query (`SELECT FROM event_member WHERE eid = 256633941116408`) for all of the invited users of this particular event (The event's ID was `256633941116408`), my results seem to be limited to 4932 users every time without fail. 59,161 users were invited to this event and *should* appear in API responses. Even manually limiting the Graph API request to 1000 per page, the response still quits at the same number of invites, only 5 pages later. Is it possible that Facebook does not expose an event's invited users for a public event past the 4932 entry mark, or am I approaching this the wrong way?

Thanks! -Robert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem and have found no solution but to repeat the task for "Accepted" "Declined" "Unsure" and "not_replied" to get as much user status as possible. I'm interested at events with more than 100000 invites. I tryed limiting the request by uids too only to face the same deception. You might want to scrap the page and conduct programming on the output, but ou would need to ask Facebook permission. Here is the Facebook web page related to that: https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php . Let us know if you find another way.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your input Alexandre, I've found that this is also the case for me. Even site scraping appears that it would be limited to the same 5000 person limit. My solution was the same as your's: repeat the task over all four response statuses.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Limit and pagination, like this:

```
SELECT uid FROM event_member where eid = 306212359507086 LIMIT 0,1000
SELECT uid FROM event_member where eid = 306212359507086 LIMIT 2000,1000
SELECT uid FROM event_member where eid = 306212359507086 LIMIT 3000,1000
.... until you get an empty response
```

also check if you have the necesary permissions, if is not your event you may only see about your friends.

try this also:

```
SELECT uid FROM event_member where eid = 306212359507086 
AND uid IN (SELECT uid1 FROM friend WHERE uid2=me()) LIMIT 0,1000
```

dont forget to change the event id